# What does meen this error: Falsy value for recipient key 'registrationTokens'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

I got this error:  Falsy value for recipient key 'registrationTokens' while working with gcm push notifications.

Below you can find my code:

```
Device.find({ user: { $in: users }}, function (err, devices) {
          if (err) {
            logger.error('500 ' + err)
            return res.status(500).json({
              code: config.errorCode.status500.code,
              message: config.errorCode.status500.message
            })
          }

        var androidRegTokens = []
        var iOSReqTokens = []

          for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            if (devices[i].platform == 'Android') {
              androidRegTokens.push(devices[i].deviceToken)
            } else {
              iOSReqTokens.push(devices[i].deviceToken)
            }
          }

          if (androidRegTokens.length > 0) {
            gcmPush('Notification is sent.', androidRegTokens)
          }

          if (iOSReqTokens.length > 0) {
            apnsPush('Notification is sent.', iOSReqTokens)
          }
          return res.json({ msg: 'Operation succeed.'})
 })
```

Body of the function gcmPush('Notification is sent.', androidRegTokens) is:

```
this.sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: deviceTokens }, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }else {
    console.log(response)
  }
})
```

Does anyone know what wrong is with my code? At first push notifications worked perfect, than this error occured each time I call the service.

**EDIT:**

I have solved this thanx to Luiz Fernando. The problem is the function:

```
gcmPush('Notification is sent.', androidRegTokens)
```

I have forgot to add title which is part of the constructor:

```
function GcmPush (title, message, deviceTokens) {
this.sender = new gcm.Sender(config.gcmSender)
this.sendPushNotification(title, message, deviceTokens)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The deviceTokens object is a falsy value, it can be: null, undefined, 0, '', NaN,false.

Maybe it happend because you are filling iOSReqTokens and androidRegTokens nested in an asynchronous operation (it seems Device.find is async). So, the callback of Device.find and the for-loop happens in different times. Probably, the for-loop is happening AFTER the response, so this response will be undefined (and really is).

So, you need to use some async control flow library, such [Promise](http://bluebirdjs.com) or [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and ensure the correct order of operations.

Also, where you use the pushed registrations?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with async control flow (Async) but the same error occurred. Then I realized that the problem was there where I use the pushed registrations. I have updated my question with the solution.